# See the location for "moving" on Google Maps timeline

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps says "moving" in the timeline, is there another way to see the location? I've looked in my Google activity & can't find any location for the time it says moving.

Comment: "moving" in the Google Maps timeline generally means that it can't pinpoint your location or doesn't have a point close enough to make a guess and ask you, so it just assumes you are "moving" around... This can also happen if the device can't get sufficient location data (GPS signal, WiFi signals, etc) to get a usable location. I have no reference for this (thus it is not an answer) but from personal experience, and I have used Timeline for many years daily as part of time-tracking for work.